# Jersey - Spring 3 autowiring (NoClassDefFoundError: EnvironmentAware)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, autowired

I'm trying to implement a proyect using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE with Jersey 1.13 on a Tomcat 7 server.
My problem is that when I tried to autowire a service into the rest implementation, the service bean turned `null` everytime.

I found a suggestion, to set this in the `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mac.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now, I get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
```

I don't know what's wrong, maybe you can help me figure this out

this is my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>localito</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mac.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this my `pom.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>localito</groupId>
        <artifactId>localito</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <description></description>
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-file</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <file>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
                                <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                                <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
                                <version>${my.version}</version>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>java.net</id>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
                <id>eclipselink</id>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
                <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2.ga</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!-- dependency>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.2</version>
            </dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.184428</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.183949</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jersey dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                <version>2.1_3</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Jersey dependency end -->
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.build.finalName>localito</project.build.finalName>
            <project.packaging>war</project.packaging>
            <my.version>1.0</my.version>
        </properties>
        <name>localito</name>
    </project>
```

I thank your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jersey-spring brings in an older version of Spring. You will have to add an exclusion:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

A `mvn dependency-tree` will show these dependencies